# Groovy sandbox blocks classes in workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have the https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin in use and it is used (git repo) for creating general helpers for pipeline jobs. I'm having problems with the groovy sandbox when trying to use class from the workflow lib repo.

I'm getting this exception:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified new <path_to_my_class>
```

By reading the documentation of the plugin, I get the impression that this common repo is trusted and classes defined there would not be sandboxed.

Additionally, it seems that if the class is defined without "class" keyword within the source file, i.e. just implements the methods passes the sandbox security check, not otherwise. But how can I have parametrized constructor without defining class and constuctor?

I would like to make the following use case work without getting blocked by the sandbox.

in "/org/mylib" directory I defined class MyClass.groovy with the following implementation.

```groovy
package org.mylib

class MyClass implements Serializable {
    MyClass(String someString) {
        this.data = someString
    }

    String data

    String data() {
        return this.data
    }
}
```

Why this is run within sandbox and how I could work around it?

Comment: Is your class in the `src/` directory? Is your library defined for the entire Jenkins instance, or just a folder? What is an example of a pipeline calling it? The question needs some more information before it can be answered properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get the approve button next to it, it is no blocking. It most likely not able to find it.

The actual [documentation mentioned on the plugin site](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) states that the layout is:

```
(root)
+- src                     # Groovy source files
|   +- org
|       +- foo
|           +- Bar.groovy  # for org.foo.Bar class
+- vars
|   +- foo.groovy          # for global 'foo' variable
|   +- foo.txt             # help for 'foo' variable
+- resources               # resource files (external libraries only)
|   +- org
|       +- foo
|           +- bar.json    # static helper data for org.foo.Bar
```

So my current guess is you should move it to src directory.

Comment: Putting sources into src -directory does not help :/

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a static method within your class that creates the instance (i.e. factory pattern) it should get around that aspect of the security plugin.